can we get plain query from Statement Execution from # https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/sql-execution-tutorial?
I m using SQL Statement API from Hive Data Brics.
https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/sql-execution-tutorial
I m using SQL Api with query and parameters list I m passing.
is it possible to get which plain query is going to be generate from that Api call ?

Please add more details of what you are trying? and expected outcomes

I have created the parameters like below:
param1 = 'value1'
param2 = 'value2'
query = f"SELECT * FROM tr1 WHERE column1 = '{param1}' AND column2 = '{param2}'"

I have tried the below approach:
sql_template = "SELECT * FROM tr1 WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ?"
final_query = sql_template
for param in parameters:
    final_query = final_query.replace("?", f"'{param}'", 1)
sql_template = "SELECT * FROM tr1 WHERE column1 = ? AND column2 = ?"
print(final_query)

Results:
SELECT * FROM tr1 WHERE column1 = 'value1' AND column2 = 'value2'

In the above code using (?) which are then replaced with actual parameter values.
